# Python List interpretation (w/ Turtles)

Tags: python

Little python question, how to make the turtle move according to `[(160, 20), (-43, 10), (270, 8), (-43, 12)]` where the first number is the angle turned and the second is distance traveled.

My attempt:

```
print('Question 11')
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor("hot pink")
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.shape("turtle")
tess.color("blue")

def path(x):
    for a, b in len(x): # Not so sure about this line.
      tess.forward(a)
      tess.right(b)
l = [(160, 20), (-43, 10), (270, 8), (-43, 12)]
path(l)
wn.mainloop()
```

Errors I have gotten:

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

and

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: `len(x)` returns the length of the sequence `x`. You want `for a, b in x`. I imagine you want to turn then move forward, not move then turn.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked great. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with turtle, but the follow line:

```
for a, b in len(x): # Not so sure about this line.
```

this line is wrong: x as the follow code means a list. len(x) returns an integer, but integer is not iterable.

which you means:

```
for a, b in x:
```

instead your code.